# Is there a complete Link Invariant for links with N crossing.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory, braid-groups

Are there known examples of pairs $\left(f, N\right)$, where $f$ is a link invariant that is known to be complete when restricted to link diagrams that have at most $N$ crossings?
(Ideally, f should have a publicly available software implementation, but one without is also ok.)